# How to simplify $42^{25\sqrt{25^{25}}}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, exponentiation, gre-exam

Am a student preparing for GRE, I have no clue to solve this am attaching the screenshot of question:

[image]

I need you give me a short cut or tip to deal such problems...

Comment: The answer choosen is the right one, but let me know how?

Comment: Are you sure $\sqrt{25^{25}}$ is in the exponent? If the actual expression is $42^{25}\cdot\sqrt{25^{25}}$, then we get $$42^{25}\cdot\sqrt{25^{25}}=21^{25}\cdot 2^{25}\cdot\sqrt{25}^{25}=21^{25}\cdot 2^{25}\cdot 5^{25}=21^{25}\cdot 10^{25},$$which obviously has $25+n$ digits. Otherwise, I'm not sure the answer is correct...

Comment: Actually thats the screenshot of my revision exam..So am 100% sure.. about the question

Comment: This looks like a formatting error in the question. The square root is in a different font and it looks like a pasted image?

Comment: But $$42^{25^\cdot 5^{25}}\gt (21^{25})^{5^{25}}\gt (10^{n-1})^{5^{25}}.$$The last expression has $(n-1)\cdot 5^{25}$ digits, which is much more than $n+25$.

Comment: yup.. i have pasted the screenshot of the question. As I was struggling to format it correctly as exponents :P

Comment: Please Guys.. let me know a quick solution, my head is on gonna explode without knowing the answer :(

Comment: If it is really in the exponent, then the correct answer would be **[E]**.

Answer (score 1):

Let us first simply this a bit:

$$42^{25 \sqrt{25^{25}}} = 42^{25 \cdot 5^{25}} = (21^{25})^{5^{25}} 2^{5^{27}}.$$

The number of digits is obtained by the logarithm, so we calculate

$$\log_{10} 42^{25 \sqrt{25^{25}}} = 5^{25} \log_{10} 21^{25} + 5^{27} \log_{10} 2.$$

Since $n = \lfloor \log_{10} 21^{25} \rfloor + 1$, I'd say that the answer is "none of the above".

The used identities can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Identities_and_properties). The check with WolframAlpha was not as simple, but here it is: [the number of digits of $21^{25}$ is $34$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=number%20of%20digits%20of%2021%5E25), and [the number of digits of $42^{1000}$ is $1624$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=number%20of%20digits%20of%2042%5E1000). I think we can agree that $25 \sqrt{25^{25}} > 1000$, and $1624 > 850 = 25 \cdot 34 = 25n$ (the other offered answers are even smaller), which I believe confirms my answer.

Comment: Nice.. so according to you @Vedran  the answer is not B.. am convinced after your calculation

Comment: No, the answer is not B; it's E. However, walcher and DepeHb gave a very probably explanation in the comments on how the error in the exam has happened.

Answer (score 1):

The proposed answer is off by such a large magnitude that it is easy to show its falsity without a calculator.

$21^{25}\lt100^{25}=10^{50}$ which has $51$ digits, and so if the answer is correct, $\large42^{25\sqrt{25^{25}}}$ can't have more than $51+25=76$ digits.

But, $\large42^{25\sqrt{25^{25}}}=42^{25^{13.5}}\gt 10^{25^{13.5}}\gt 10^{25^2}=10^{625}$ which has $626$ digits.

So, the given answer is wrong unless the expression is $42^{25}\cdot\sqrt{25^{25}}$ as pointed out in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

The exam is wrong.

A number $n$ has $\lfloor \log_{10} n\rfloor + 1$ decimal digits. So $21^{25}$ has $34$ digits.

For the more complicated expression,

$$1+\lfloor \log_{10} 42^{25\sqrt{25^{25}}} \rfloor = 1+\lfloor \log_{10} 42^{\sqrt{25^{27}}} \rfloor = 1+\lfloor \log_{10} 42^{5^{27}} \rfloor = 1+\lfloor 5^{27} \log_{10} 42 \rfloor$$
which according to my calculator is over $10^{19}$, greater than $34+25.$